# How to fix faulty definition of "i" in for loops

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a data frame "data_all" which is a list containing 67 elements. 
For each element, I'm calculating the mean of the first column, "EDA". 
To do so, I use for-loops:

```r
for (i in seq_along(data_all)) { 
  mean_all[i] <- print(round(mean(data_all[[i]][["EDA"]]), digits=3)) 
}
```

The problem: 
In the global environment, the "i" is defined as "1L", one single value instead of 67 values.  Values: i = 1L

I tried deleting the "i" value with rm(i) and loaded the codes again. I also closed and restarted the program and imported all data again. 
For some reason, "i" is registered as "1L" even though my "data_all" list contains 67 elements. 
At some point, I was able to do the calculations and the code worked. The next time I opened the program, it didn't work anymore.

I tried googling the problem but couldn't find anyone having the same issues.

Here are extracts from my r-code:

Imported data:

```r
filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.dat", full.names=FALSE)
data_all <- lapply(filenames, function(x) read.delim(x, "", header = TRUE, sep = ";", quote = "\"", dec = ",", fill = TRUE))
```

For-loop:

```r
for (i in seq_along(data_all)) { 
  mean_all[i] <- print(round(mean(data_all[[i]][["EDA"]]), digits=3)) 
}
```

Error:

> [1] 10.938
>   Error: object 'mean_all' not found`

I expected a list of 67 elements:

```r
[1] 10.56
[1] 12.46
...
[1] 13.72
```

instead, I only receive a single result:

```r
[1] 10.938
```

and since "i" only contains one value instead of 67, r could not save the output as a new variable "mean_all[i]"

I would appreciate any help regarding this problem. I don't mind looking into it myself if I just knew where to look for help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps first set aside an empty vector/list/data frame named `mean_all` e.g `mean_all <- numeric()` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try it out!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that actually worked! I used ‘mean_all <- vector("numeric", length = length(data_all))‘ beforehand and now I have the right output.

Comment: Incidentally, `i` is just an integer counter, so it wouldn't be 67 values anyway. Or did you mean `i = 67` was what you were expecting it to show once the loop had finished iterating?